# How do I turn off highlighting in celery?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm using the celery managment command to do some debugging in a django application:

```
python manage.py celeryd -l info
```

The output is highilighted in really glaring colors.  Is there any way to turn the highlighting off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure or disable the color with `CELERYD_LOG_COLOR` http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-log-color

Comment: can also set that via the command line: `celeryd -- .log_color=no`

Comment: For me, starting celery with the argument `--no-color` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

i guess you could pipe it through `cat`:

```
python manage.py celeryd -l info |cat
```

Comment: even after piping it is colorful